# Filtering a request based on query parameters not present in model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have an endpoint that lets you search for events between two dates.

`/events?start_time=X&end_time=X`

Events are a model with:

- id
- name
- event_date

Should we be doing validation on the `start_time` and `end_time` parameters in the View, Serializer, or Model?

We want to make sure the `start_time` parameter is included, `end_time` is optional, and ensure that both are well formatted dates.

Is this custom logic in the view or is there a set of helpers that DRF (or Django) provides to perform this validation?

Comment: use decorators for verifying that your both/single date(s) is formatted correctly and i hope that query sets you can do very easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/), so it should be done on the queryset in the view. Validation of that data should also be done there I guess. You may use a dedicated serializer to validate that data (in `get_queryset` for example).

However, I would suggest using [django-filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) which will take care if the validation for you.

Maybe a filterset like this:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class EventFilterset(filters.FilterSet)
    start_time=filters.DateFilter(name='event_date', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_time=filters.DateFilter(name='event_date', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model=Events
        fields=['start_time', 'end_time']
```

I'm not sure if you need the `class Meta` part.

Full documentation [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).